# How do I avoid losing to lower rated players?

Tags: tournament

I'm a Class B chess player. I'm afraid of playing low rated players because if I lose my rating goes drastically down. Sometimes low rated chess players are underrated or they play really good one game against a stronger player.

Comment: If you sometimes win against a higher rated player but never lose to a lower rated player, your rating is probably too low and a bad measure of your playing strength.

Comment: _"because if I lose my rating goes drastically down"_ Why would that matter?

Comment: Lose more games until you have the lowest possible rating.

Comment: @StudentT is a problem solver :-D

Comment: What is class B?

Comment: @David Class B in the United States Chess Federation is a rating that categorizes a player as slightly above average across the entire US chess-playing community.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I still have no clue of how strong that is! Why do Americans always need to measure things differently?

Comment: @David we don't. Other countries do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, losing is part of chess. If losing didn't suck, then winning wouldn't rock.

Ratings are approximations. Don't let your rating define you.

The way to prevent lower rated players from defeating you is to not allow them to do so. Improve your play such that you can adequately punish the superficial hope-chess moves that "C" players play.

edit - There's no magic wand wand we can wave to help you. There is only working harder so you can play better moves.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to be overconfident. That is almost always the case for which you are describing. I would recommend avoiding looking at the opponents rating until after the game.